# How do I manage multiple overlays on different buttons clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, vimeo-api

```js
function toggleOverlay_1() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox_1');
  overlay.style.opacity = .8;
  if (overlay.style.display == "block") {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function toggleOverlay_2() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox_2');
  overlay.style.opacity = .8;
  if (overlay.style.display == "block") {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
div#overlay {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
div#specialBox_1 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
div#specialBox_2 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
div#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="specialBox">
    <iframe id="myVid_1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/183364240?api=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&player_id=myVid_1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div class="closebtn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleOverlay_1();">&times;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay">
  <div id="specialBox">
    <iframe id="myVid_2" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/183364240?api=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&player_id=myVid_2" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div class="closebtn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleOverlay_2();">&times;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="button" name="Google_Red" class="button_red" value="Google" a href="#" onclick="toggleOverlay_1()"></input>
  <br>

  <input type="button" name="W3Schools Red" class="button_red" value="Sealed Air" a href="#" onclick="toggleOverlay_2()"></input>
  <br>
</div>
```

I am trying to open different videos(in an overlay) on different button clicks. I could this well if I use just one button and its opens the video correctly. But when I try to bind different videos to different buttons, it just binds one videos to all the buttons. Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: It'd be easier for contributors if you made the code runnable, on something like JSFiddle.

Comment: @PaulBGD I did! Thanks to Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your html and jquery. Here is what you need to do. Instead of making 2 functions. Keep one function for toggle with the iframe id as parameter the `toggleOverlay(playerid)`. As your video iframe id's parent div is the specialbox and the specialbox parent is the overlay itself. You can utilize the .parent() method of jquery to set it up.

```
function toggleOverlay(playerid){
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").parent().css("opacity",".8");
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").parent().toggle();
  $("#" + playerid).parent("#specialBox").toggle();
}
```

Now in the buttons or anywhere you call the toggleOverlay function, add the unique playerid as parameter and your set based on which button handles which overlay.

Also you cant have 2 divs with same ids. So change the second overlay div id to "overlay2".

Here is working example:

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/pEmEJE

Comment: I tried to autoplay the videos by adding autoplay=1 in my src. But all the videos keep looping in the background, even if the overlay is closed. Can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with autoplay. Please note we have customized the video play and stop based on custom need so if you want to auto play the videos on some condition then you will have to put that in the jquery code in the appropriate place to do so. The autoplay query parameter i would not recommend as it will start the video player as soon as the page loads even when the overlay is not showing.

Comment: E.g. if you want the video to start playing right after you click the apply overlay button then put the following line at the end in the toggleOverlay function: $f($("#" + playerid)[0]).api('play');

Answer (score 0):

Because you are targeting the div with an ID, the DOM will take the first div with that id (your first video). So you have to target your second overlay with another ID.

Comment: So should I change id="overlay" to different ID's?

Comment: @SailiG ID's should always be different. So one could be `id="overlay"` the other `id="overlay2"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rebuild option, I feel like this might be easier than making all that javascript for each video.

```js
// This part isnt needed but I added it in case you wanted it

// Get the modals
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('id02');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
}
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 600px
}
.container {
  padding: 0.01em 16px
}
.closebtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.closebtn:hover,
.closebtn:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Open Video 1</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Open Video 2</button>

<!-- Video 1 -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/183364240?api=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&player_id=myVid_1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Video 2 -->
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/183364240?api=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&player_id=myVid_2" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Rick. But I want to use the vimeo api and make the code function like this - https://codeshare.io/QgN4P. I need the videos to be played in full screen. When I click on the small 'X' button on the right hand side of the video overlay, I want the overlay to be hidden as well as the video to be pause and then unloaded.

Comment: I minimized some of your code.  https://jsfiddle.net/are99tmq/
There is a live preview here: http://www.paymaster.net/net3/test/13/

The environment im working in wont load the videos, just an error so let me know if the script still works on your side.